# Convert a string to sentence case

Tags: code-golf, string

**Input:**

A string (or the closest thing to that in your language)

**Output:**

The same string but converted to sentence case

**Rules:**

- For this challenge, sentence case can be considered "`The first letter of each sentence is capitalized. The rest are lowercase.`" (i.e. proper nouns do not have to be capitalized)
- If the input does not include a period, it is treated as one sentence.
- The other 2 punctuation marks used to end a sentence in english (`?` and `!`) can be considered periods
- If a letter immediately follows a punctuation mark the same rules still apply (i.e. the first letter is capitalized and all following letters are lowercased until the next punctuation mark)

**Sample test cases:**

```
"hello world." // "Hello world."

"CODEGOLF IS FUN." // "Codegolf is fun."

"no period" // "No period"

"the ball was red. so was the balloon." // "The ball was red. So was the balloon." 

"I love codegolf.stackexchange.com" // "I love codegolf.Stackexchange.Com"

"heLLo! hOW are yOU toDay? hOpEfulLy yOu are okay!" // "Hello! How are you today? Hopefully you are okay!"
```

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!**

Comment: Suggested test case: “Everybody loves codegolf.stackexchange.com !!! ♡ 4 golf”.

Comment: *All other punctuation marks* - so `"`, `'`, `,`, `;`, `-`, ...?

Comment: You wouldn't normally capitalize a sentence after every `"`, `'`, `,`, `;`, `-`.
The challenge is to convert to standard sentence case

Comment: @Lebster I'll vote to re-open if you specify exactly which punctuation marks can end a sentence (if it's just `.`, `?` and `!` then remove the word "etc." since it adds ambiguity). A few more test cases would also be very helpful

Comment: It should also be specified what happens if there is a letter immediately after a period, or if that's even possible

Comment: Huh, I thought I had done those two things, I guess it must not have saved :(
Doing again now, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: "The other 2 punctuation marks used to end a sentence in english (? and !) can be considered periods" Are we able to replace these punctuation marks with periods? e.g. `"heLLo! hOW are yOU toDay? hOpEfulLy yOu are okay!" // "Hello. How are you today. Hopefully you are okay."`

Comment: @AaronMiller No

Comment: By a 'letter' do you mean just `a`-`z` and `A`-`Z` or must we also cater for accented characters as in `Crème Brulée`.

Comment: Your program can work with accented characters or it can break when fed with them, it is up to you

Comment: Some other cases: (1) Should `hello.   world` (more than one space after the period) should be converted to `Hello.  World`? (2) Can there be "empty sentences" -- e.g. `.  ` or `hello? !`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
l.ª
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/R@/Qqv//SzJSFZISc3IUyhOLFYpSU/QUivPBbJhEfn6eHgA)

Nothing like a good old built-in answer! This converts the string to lowercase and then performs sentence case.

Comment: haha get outgolfed nerd.

Comment: I like how you've commented "get outgolfed nerd" on your own answer. xD

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
¡
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiwqEiLCIiLCJoZWxsbyB3b3JsZC5cbkNPREVHT0xGIElTIEZVTi5cbm5vIHBlcmlvZFxudGhlIGJhbGwgd2FzIHJlZC4gc28gd2FzIHRoZSBiYWxsb29uLlxuSSBsb3ZlIGNvZGVnb2xmLnN0YWNrZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tXG5oZUxMbyEgaE9XIGFyZSB5T1UgdG9EYXk/IGhPcEVmdWxMeSB5T3UgYXJlIG9rYXkhIl0=)

"Nothing like a good old built-in answer!" I suppose not younger lyxal, I suppose not.

Alternatively, a non-trivial 24 byte answer:

```
`([.?!])`ṡλ⇩⌈:Th~iǐȦṄ;Ẇṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiYChbLj8hXSlg4bmhzrvih6nijIg6VGh+aceQyKbhuYQ74bqG4bmFIiwiIiwiaGVsbG8gd29ybGQuXG5DT0RFR09MRiBJUyBGVU4uXG5ubyBwZXJpb2RcbnRoZSBiYWxsIHdhcyByZWQuIHNvIHdhcyB0aGUgYmFsbG9vbi5cbkkgbG92ZSBjb2RlZ29sZi5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNvbVxuaGVMTG8hIGhPVyBhcmUgeU9VIHRvRGF5PyBoT3BFZnVsTHkgeU91IGFyZSBva2F5ISJd)

### Explained

```
`([.?!])`ṡλ⇩⌈:Th~iǐȦṄ;Ẇṅ
`       `ṡ               # Split the input on the regex "[.?!]", keeping the thing that causes splits (wrapping something in `()` when regex splitting keeps it in the split list)
          λ          ;Ẇ  # To each second item of that list (guaranteed to not be punctuation), starting at index 0:
           ⇩⌈             #   Split the lowercase version of the string on spaces
             :Th~i        #   Get the first word by getting the first truthy index in the splitted string (because it may contain `""`s) and get the item at that index
                  ǐȦṄ     #   Replace the word at that index with a title-cased version of the string, and join the list on spaces.
                      ṅ   # Join the result on nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to Surculose Sputum*

If other punctuation like `!` or `?` are allowed.

```python
lambda s:re.sub(r'\w[\w ]+',lambda x:x[0].capitalize(),s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYy9asMwFEZ3PcXnKRINpqWboXio8welHkqnOINcy7HgRldISpX05d1QWrodzoHjr2li9ziPT91M@tQPGrEKpoznXoZFl/ddxuFusfxtl@qyvz@UH9rbpMl@GamWUQl78hwSgpnzZMngoRLwwbokR2mdPyeplJonQ8TIHGgoxXPbrDbtyxq7N6zfX0vhGN4Ey4NIk0GviZB1vD2HGpF/@C8wu1ps/29FUaBh7EDt5wpHptG6Y42riTfXtN8)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda s:'. '.join(map(str.capitalize,s.split('. ')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco9C8IwEIDhPb/iNlOQgI4FJ7UiiB3ETZCrSenJNReSSNA/Xz/A7YXnDc88iF9O/eoyMY6dRUj1zMDM3IW8HjHolKO5YaCMTC83TyYFpqy/U1VVUxmIHSxqBSGSz9DriOVKPjyy/vDgmAWKRLZGrdvNdtceGtifoDkfjfICwUUSq/LgoENmKJggOmsgya//IOLNGw)

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYy9asMwFEZ3PcXnKRINpqWboXio8welHkqnOINcy7HgRldISpX05d1QWrodzoHjr2li9ziPT91M@tQPGrEKpoznXoZFl/ddxuFusfxtl@qyvz@UH9rbpMl@GamWUQl78hwSgpnzZMngoRLwwbokR2mdPyeplJonQ8TIHGgoxXPbrDbtyxq7N6zfX0vhGN4Ey4NIk0GviZB1vD2HGpF/@C8wu1ps/29FUaBh7EDt5wpHptG6Y42riTfXtN8) in Python 3, since you can use `x[0]` instead of `x.group(0)`.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum I wasn't aware of that trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 77 bytes

If non-periods are allowed... well, that greatly golfs my program!

```erlang
g(H)->[string:titlecase(string:lowercase(I))||I<-re:split(H,"(\\W[\\W ]+)")].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/BasMwDIbvfQrNJ5slfoAwusPWLoHQHMrYIcnBa7TUoNrBFuTSd0@9scJg0Ap0@fR/gh8DGTfmGA/BTrysllGWKl@3kYN1Y8GWCQ8movwF5GcMP6BS6nyunvKARZzIsiwzIbvuo00L/aMSqtfLyVgn215Bvl5BGuuLrzlYRjlKcUQiD7MPNGihVJaOjqTK/idfmtfNW1NvodrD9n13J@08TBisH27Hyk1dNxqiOU2EwBgZvovdlsyu4RLDw/PVu6/wEeHTECXDDhl0IqbSJsKVe@90J/780MsF)

### Explanation

```erlang
g(H)->                      % Define a function.

re:split(H,"(\\W[\\W ]+)")  % Split the operand on "sentences", keeping the items reserved for splitting.

                            % I.e. none of the items from the string is missing after the split

||I<-   ]                   % For every item in a sentence,
[string:titlecase(string:lowercase(I))

                            %     Title case the sentence.
.                           % End the function.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 101 bytes

```javascript
s=>(s.reduce((a,c)=>c=='.'?(r+=c,'Upp'):c>' '?(r+=c['to'+a+'erCase'](),'Low'):(r+=c,a),'Upp',r=''),r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDBbsIwDAbg@57C6sWJGsJ9UrpDgW0SggNwmnYIaQpFURwlZX38roJtmmhvkX9/VuyL/tLJxCa0M0@V7WvVJ1WwJKOtrsYypoXhqjBKocQXFnNlBB5CQP5sCoSf0ge2hLnO0cZSJ4ufjAtcUzd03YnmdyWiQuQi8t6QT@SsdHRiNcvO1jmCjqKrZCZTcE3Lhk7OYT6H7O1/@vRAy@1i@bpdr@B9B6vDZoKXw2YncjU0CeqrH4/wBMHGhqqx3fxFj6g9Wzhq56DTCYZzSUh0e/8GRH7iM/sR200w6L8B)

Comment: Woah, how does this work lol

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>80</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>87</s></sup> 76 bytes

Added 13 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [Abigail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95135/abigail).

```c
c;b;f(char*s){for(b=1;c=*s;b|=ispunct(c))*s++=isalpha(c)?b?b=0,c&95:c|32:c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFNU8IwFLzzK95k1OkHH0WHg8TKAUWdceCAniiHNk1oZkrTSdphFPrba1vaiuC7JG@zu0n2kd6GkDwn2MNMI4ErDaXvmZCaZw8xsQ2FvYPNVZxGJNGIrhvKNIveDePALfqJN/Fsq0tu7kdjcri7HROc5VuXR5oO@w4UVXlCQlWiVmuwa7QsFNAwFLATMvT7qAsDA9DrKQTG4Jc8XTw9vyzeZ/C2hNnnvBFMhU83ImTAFbA0OhNFAmIqufBr9rzt/9CSgILnhiHsXAWS@n1Qoto3B0JEzYUfF9zlP9wLe3cr0igpX3k1HKHW6QyuVRluowMvZYzK1dCyrPURLqfDS1GRpoWL5QEU/6aCaVXK@qDuquR1DKbJ9ZPYVSJJ/KUdfbv1ZPhaxy0jloU905CDrpWDoPcIDip@f1Sc8Jh2ATXSUuhE56Ksk@U/)

**How**

Capitalises the first letter and every letter after a punctuation mark.  Every other letter is converted to lower case. Simply prints everything else.

Comment: This fails on `the amount is $15`. Regardless of whether you interpret `$` as a punctuation character, the `1` should remain as is, it being its own uppercase.

Comment: @Abigail Oops, wasn't dealing with numeric chars. Fixed now - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 13 bytes

```
.+
$T
\b .
$L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9Pm0slhCsmSUGPS8Xn//@M1JycfIXy/KKcFD0uZ38XV3d/HzcFz2AFt1A/Pa68fIWC1KLM/BSukoxUhaTEnByF8sRihaLUFD2F4nwwGyaRn5@nBwA)

### Explanation

General approach is to convert every word to title-case, then un-convert the words that shouldn't have been converted

`.+` Matches the entire string, `$T` converts it to title case (every word lowercase with an uppercase first character

`\b .` - `\b` Matches the position between a word-character and a non-word character (i.e. the end of a word without a full stop) followed by a space and any other character `.`

`$L` converts this to lowercase

Answer (score 3):

## perl -p, 33 bytes

```
$_=lc=~s/(^|\pP)\s*\K\pL/uc$&/erg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYn2bauWF8jriamIEAzplgrxjumwEe/NFlFTT@1KP3//4zUnJx8hfL8opwUPS5nfxdXd38fNwXPYAW3UD89rrx8hYLUosz8FK6SjFSFpMScHIXyxGKFotQUPYXifDAbJpGfn6fHlZafrwPkFYGIqn/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

This lowercases the string, then upper cases any letter following either the beginning of the string, or after a punctuation character (skipping any whitespace in between). This does turn a string `"foo, bar, baz"` into `"Foo, Bar, Baz"`, but that's how I read the requirement about all punctuation.

Comment: You can save two bytes by making the lc and the substitution separate statements. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYn2bpYXyOuJqYgQDOmWCvGO6bAR780WUVNPzX9//@M1JycfIXy/KKcFD0uZ38XV3d/HzcFz2AFt1A/Pa68fIWC1KLM/BSukoxUhaTEnByF8sRihaLUFD2F4nwwGyaRn5@nx5WWn68D5BWBiKp/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 117 bytes

```python
import re
f=lambda s:''.join(map(lambda p:re.sub(r'[a-z]',lambda m:m[0].upper(),p.lower(),1),re.split(r'([.?!])',s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJBb9pAEIXv/IqBHOyV6KpVblQoSgiBSCSuSqIeKIe1PcZO1jur3XXA/fN0TYAUk95Gb97neTtjXbuc1OV2W5SajAODnWwoRRmnAuwgCPgLFSoshQ73oh4Y5LaKQxMsxJc/y6C/b5SDcvF1ySut0YSsr7mk9a76xvoNomXhPBQu@FV3yYK@ZYxtU8zAIYYbNtCmUM4X3w26yijYdDoXMCneUHmHdZAIi7YjrEUfs2GysJejlARrMjLlPcZgOITe9F@t5R9Ft@NJNLuD@zncPT8emRGluCKZQWEhq9QZpwj8qwpKD8DjUWg5XY4QCylhLaxfZsrB0q4@NIjUcezTmXn@iRlaI@5B0htCss/MrRPJK26SXKgV8oTKw@fbxvmJceSNZ@uczagLefQLhEGoo2dwdCvqKy/pcVbJWe3FatekV1F3T3behSmt30GqPJg24JQ0elDWO/EDbI473jgj/n9cwWOeHCZc8xs@6n12fg6wIkrjGk/SeHmyl9v7Cx7gGn5GN9HTcVNBCQIMxeR8svc/MfitfjRgCs2FPlLygG3/Ag)

For some reason, I made a solution that handles a few extra test cases that OP may or may not have cared about :) This is much longer than the current shortest Python solution, but I'd be sad to just throw this code away, so here it is!

Extra test cases:

```python
"a.b.c" //  "A.B.C"
(no space after punctuation)

"hello.  goodbye" // "Hello.  Goodbye"
(more than one space after punctuation)

"I'M A ROBOT" // "I'm a robot"
(punctuation other than sentence terminator)
```

Commented solution:

```python
f = (
  lambda string:
    ''.join(map(

      # Capitalize first letter in part
      lambda part: re.sub(
        r'[a-z]',
        lambda match: match[0].upper(),
        part.lower(),
        1
      ),

      # Split on punctuation
      re.split(r'([.?!])',string)

    ))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 192 bytes

```go
import(y"bytes";."regexp";u"unicode")
type k=[]byte
func f(s k)k{return MustCompile(`\w[\w ]+`).ReplaceAllFunc(s,func(b k)k{return append(k{byte(u.ToUpper(rune(b[0])))},y.ToLower(b[1:])...)})}
```

A port of [@dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204825/77309).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZLfatswFMZhd_VTnOpKYp263Y2VMUbarAGvLkvDLtJAZVv-gxVJyNJcE_IkuwmDPcTu9hrb00y2w5L9AV9ZfDrn953PR5-_5Gr3TbOkYjmHNStlUK61MhZQtrboq7PZs5c_vg8ablHcWl6jC4oMz_mjRhcOOVkmKuWIBLbVHKrXy1VXFWROJpDhGipSbQy3zkh472o7UWtdCo4f7pvlfQOrpw-EfuBasIS_FWLqu3B91jXj-LiVac1liqtNB8eO3qmFVww2TnIcL5-vCCHbs9broWq8Hi9fvFoRSinZku2Q4-eTWT9UFxMT2AQn5-eArrkQChplREpRcOJj01tTSiskrq0_5DjDQySMiuNab0gGxMTnz5XIoKzBO4xiJtHl1bsonMJsDtPFzTHqRoFPVap0jCF_Fx6a7woOMRMCGlaD4SmFuerPdn-h1Phw9h9I_R_IwXQGQn3ikOz_AZ1b_5r4Y1IwmXPqtz1m-Deg_gOQeMDBrF_WKVyrBpjh0CoHVqWsfeMlzTMnRNuL3aWqWHs6vtEw9MAi-jgAo4UHXnbAItJXHhh6YHQM7IfZv6jdbvj-Ag)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 19 bytes

```
T`L`l
T`l`L`^.|\W .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyTBJyGHKyQhB0jH6dXEhCvo/f@fkZqTk69Qnl@Uk6LH5ezv4uru7@Om4Bms4Bbqp8eVl69QkFqUmZ/CVZKRqpCUmJOjUJ5YrFCUmqKoUJwPZsMk8vPz9AA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`L`l
```

Lowercase everything.

```
T`l`L`^.|\W .
```

Uppercase the first character and any character that follows a non-word character and a space. It might not be the world's best heuristic but it works on the test case.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 81 bytes

```
func[s][parse lowercase s[any[any" "p: change skip(p/1 - 32)thru["."|"!"|"?"]]]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZDBTsMwDIbvfQo3JzisCLjtwA5sg0kVlUAThyiHLHGbqiGOkpZSiXcvYVstWfL/2Zb8O6Ce31EDF1m9nuvBKR4F9zJEBEsjBiVTFbl0038yYH4NykjXJNq1/sbf3cMKHh9uexMGzgr2y/KUGyaEiGKuKaBUBmIfWtcAzyAFe0VrCUYKVhfsgp6r7e6lKvdw@ID98W3BjsBjaElfdW8QTtJaGGWEgLqASOd6aRC5ZfeQHHwjKNLYkK2L2EvV4c/l@kLR13XOYFlSDqb6BBkQpuoIPW3ltEnI7@rBllOCw7lJnZxylqUXJT89cEV@Wsyx1ROD@qqEmP8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

*Saved 1 byte by using `~` to toggle casing instead of `vU`.*

```
v$uqq~/[.!?]
w@qq@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v0yltLCwTj9aT9E@lqvcobDQofD//4xUH598RYUM/3CFxKJUhUr/UIWSfJfESnugUIFrWmmOTyVQsBQsmZ@dWKlX4pFZrBDs6leSmpfsqpCRWKyQ568QXJDonKqQlJrmH5SqkBmiBwA)

Explanation:

```
v$u                 # Selects whole line and changes it to lowercase
   qq               # Starts recording macro q
     ~              # Toggles uppercase on current character
      /[.!?]        # Jumps to next . ! or ?
            w       # Jumps to next non-whitespace character
             @q     # Calls macro q recursively
               q@q  # Ends macro q and calls it
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
v r"^.|%W ."_u
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=diByIl4ufCVXIC4iX3U&input=ImhlTExvISBoT1cgYXJlIHlPVSB0b0RheT8gaE9wRWZ1bEx5IHlPdSBhcmUgb2theSEi)